# Insert Into Syntax Issues

Tags: ms-access, vba

I think I may have this insert into sql table issue resolved. I keep hitting a SYNTAX ERROR issue and it is highlighting the whole QDF.SQL= "INSERT INTO..... portion. I am trying to troubleshoot what I did wrong. Any experts out there that can spot what my issue is?

```
Public Function Update()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Dim rs As Recordset

Dim err As DAO.Error

Const DestinationTableName = "AC_CDData"

Const ConnectionString = _
        "ODBC;" & _
            "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
            "Server=GAALPSVR031B\P003,49503;" & _
            "Database=DB;" & _
            "UID=ID;" & _
            "PWD=PW;"
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("CDData", dbOpenTable)

qdf.Connect = ConnectionString

Do While Not rs.EOF

    qdf.SQL = "INSERT INTO ac_cddata_1(EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Region, District, Function1, Gender, EEOC, Division, Center, MeetingReadinessLevel, ManagerReadinessLevel, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee1, DevelopmentForEmployee2, DevelopmentForEmployee3, DevelopmentForEmployee4, DevelopmentForEmployee5, Justification, Changed, JobGroupCode, JobDesc, JobGroup) " & _
               "Values (" & _
               "'" & rs.EmployeeID & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.EmployeeName & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Region & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.District & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Function1 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Gender & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.EEOC & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Division & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Center & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.MeetingReadinessLevel & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.ManagerReadinessLevel & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.EmployeeFeedback & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.DevelopmentForEmployee1 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.DevelopmentForEmployee2 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.DevelopmentForEmployee3 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.DevelopmentForEmployee4 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.DevelopmentForEmployee5 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Justification & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Changed & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.JobGroupCode & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.JobDesc & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.JobGroup"')"


qdf.ReturnsRecords = False
On Error GoTo Update_qdfError
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
On Error GoTo 0

rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close

Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Exit Function

Update_qdfError:
For Each err In DAO.Errors
    MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & err.Number
Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error when building your string ...

```sql
"'" & rs.JobGroup"')"
```

Change it to this ...

```sql
"'" & rs.JobGroup & "')"
```

It's often easier to spot problems by using a string variable to hold your SQL statement.

```sql
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO ..."
```

Then you can inspect the string ...

```sql
Debug.Print strInsert
```

And finally assign the string to your querydef ...

```sql
qdf.SQL = strInsert
```

Comment: That fixed that issue now I am getting a TYPE MISMATCH error and it is highlighting SET RS = CURRENTDB.OPENRECORDSET("CDDATA", "DBOPENTABLE)

Comment: try this then: `set rs = currentdb().openRecordset("CDDATA", dbOpenDynaset)`

Comment: Don't use quotes around DBOPENTABLE.  It's the name of a constant so should not be quoted.

Comment: Use this declaration: `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset`

Comment: That Worked HansUp, is there a way to get the data to be deleted from the CDDATA TABLE once the insert happens, or do I need to make this an Append Query?

Comment: Do you mean discard all records from `CDDATA` or only the one you just inserted to the other table?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment to ask a question but by the look of your statement, `EmployeeId` I'm going to assume is of integer type. If the ID is an integer, try:

```
qdf.SQL = "INSERT INTO ac_cddata_1(EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Region, District, Function1, Gender, EEOC, Division, Center, MeetingReadinessLevel, ManagerReadinessLevel, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee1, DevelopmentForEmployee2, DevelopmentForEmployee3, DevelopmentForEmployee4, DevelopmentForEmployee5, Justification, Changed, JobGroupCode, JobDesc, JobGroup) " & _
               "Values (" & _
               & rs.EmployeeID & ", " & _
               "'" & rs.EmployeeName & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Region & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.District & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Function1 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Gender & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.EEOC & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Division & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Center & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.MeetingReadinessLevel & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.ManagerReadinessLevel & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.EmployeeFeedback & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.DevelopmentForEmployee1 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.DevelopmentForEmployee2 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.DevelopmentForEmployee3 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.DevelopmentForEmployee4 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.DevelopmentForEmployee5 & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Justification & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.Changed & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.JobGroupCode & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.JobDesc & "', " & _
               "'" & rs.JobGroup"')"
```

Otherwise, what does the error say?

Comment: They are all text type

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference the fields in your recordset with `rs.fieldName`, and that is not the correct way to do it. The right way is:

```
rs![EmployeeId]
```

(Square brackets are optional if your field names don't have spaces)

Also, as HansUp pointed in his answer, you missed the last ampersand... you forgot to put the last `&` in the last line of your string: `"'" & rs.JobGroup"')"` should be "'" & rs.JobGroup & "')"

Comment: I just made that change (none of mine are in need of []) but I am getting the same Syntax Error.